# ubuntu 18.04 LTS Intel i7 Graphics vulkan issue

Tags: vulkan

i'm aware there're many post like this, i followed instructions from those, and it's still not working for me..., this is what i have tried:

i searched in googled by error message `VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED` plus "ubuntu 18", i also searched "ubuntu 18 install vulkan", etc.. there's many posts, i've installed every packages suggested in those post, i didn't see any other action plan

```
$ apt list --installed | grep vulkan

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libvulkan-dev/bionic-updates,now 1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libvulkan1/bionic-updates,now 1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
mesa-vulkan-drivers/bionic-updates,now 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
vulkan-utils/bionic-updates,now 1.1.70+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

my specs:

- Intel CPU i7 10th gen, integrated GPU, no other GPU
- ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop version, upgraded from 16.04 LTS

when i run `vulkaninfo`, i got below error:

```
$ vulkaninfo
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.70

/build/vulkan-UL09PJ/vulkan-1.1.70+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:2700: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

please help, thank you!

Comment: What other posts are you following? What do they say to do include this in your question.

Comment: hello, i searched in googled by error message VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED plus ubuntu 18, i also searched ubuntu 18 install vulkan, etc.. there's many posts, i've installed every packages suggested in those post `sudo apt-get install vulkan-tools vulkan-utils vulkan-validationlayers libvulkan1 libvulkan-dev mesa_vulkan-drivers`

Comment: Please do not post in comments what you can and should edit in the question.

Comment: question updated